# Как заставить input типа datetime-local отображать дату в utc-формате?

Tags: html5, angularjs, datetime

Имеется `<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="StartDateTime"/>`.

Если я ввожу значение в **input**, в поле записывается дата и время с учётом **UTC** (т.е. с учётом сдвига по часовым поясам). Т.е. если на моём компьютере установлен часовой пояс *GMT+3*, и я укажу в **input** дату `01.01.2016 03.00.00` то в переменную `$scope.StartDateTime` запишется `01.01.2016 00.00.00`. Это меня не совсем устраивает. Как сделать так, чтобы **input** отображал дату в *UTC*-формате (реальное значение, присвоенное переменной)?

Comment: это стандартное поведение даты в яваскрипте

Comment: @Grundy, это я уже понял. Меня интересует, можно ли как-то обойти это стандартное поведение?

Comment: в каком браузере пробовали?

Comment: @Grundy, Chrome.

Comment: из стандарта убрали type="datetime" - по этому не совсем понятно, что вы вводите и как проверяете. Он как текст отрабатывает. Можете добавить пример в сниппете прямо в вопросе, либо на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)?

Comment: @Grundy, извиняюсь, type="datetime-local".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38430/discussion-between-grundy-and-klutch1991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве варианта, можно сделать директиву, которая будет при выводе убирать таймзому, а при вводе добавлять

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.StartDateTimeUTC = new Date();
    $scope.StartDateTime = new Date();
    $scope.getDateStrUtc = function(date) {
      return date.toUTCString();
    }
  })
  .directive('toUtc', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(s, e, a, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(d) {
          return new Date(d.getTime() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        });
        ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(d) {
          return new Date(d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="datetime-local" to-utc ng-model="StartDateTimeUTC" />
  <br/>{{StartDateTimeUTC}}
  <br />{{StartDateTimeUTC|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss':'UTC'}}
  <br/>{{getDateStrUtc(StartDateTimeUTC)}}
  <hr/><input type="datetime-local" ng-model="StartDateTime" />
  <br/>{{StartDateTime}}
  <br />{{StartDateTime|date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss':'UTC'}}
  <br/>{{getDateStrUtc(StartDateTime)}}
</div>
```