# Мгновенное переписывание input value в angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Можно сделать подобное, на angularjs?

[Ссылка на пример](http://uspresort.com/direct-mail-roi-calculator)

Интересует именно ввод в input(автоматически добавляются тысячные разделители и знак доллара), на jquery это реализовать не составляет проблем, а на angular?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точно так же реализуется, но в директиве. Только вот совсем это не просто... И, кстати, на jQuery это вообще не реализуется, т. к. оно не покрывает selection. Тут по-любому взаимодействие с нативными методами.

Comment: пример использования парсеров и форматтеров можно увидеть ответе к вопросу [Как заставить input типа datetime-local отображать дату в utc-формате?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513320/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-input-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-datetime-local-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-utc-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5/513347#513347)

Comment: @Qwertiy получается, для реализации таких решений лучше воспользоваться js/jquery чем angular?

Comment: @Grundy так это совсем непохоже даже на то что в примере

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, естественно, ведь в примере работа с datetime, а тебе нужно просто число. Важно только как получать значение из инпута с помощью парсера, и как выводить в него - с помощью форматтера